# does anyone know a JSON decoder für Cache 2008 (native Cache)

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I have to decode the response of a rest service (only JSON response). Does anyone know how to do this in Cache 2008.2?

Answer (score 1):

2008 version does not natively support JSON. 
Try these libraries.

- https://openexchange.intersystems.com/package/Cogs-JSON-Class
- https://github.com/PlanetCache/CacheJSON